# App startup without storyboard - UIViewController is still not visible

Tags: ios, swift

After reading https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-start-an-app-without-storyboard-5f57e3251a25

I have performed the following steps

1. Remove `Main.storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.storyboard` from the project
2. Remove **Main** from **Main Interface** under **Deployment Info**
3. Remove reference to `Main.storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.storyboard` from `Info.plist`

Here's some screenshots of the above steps

[image]

[image]

In `AppDelegate.swift`, I have make the following modification

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        window!.rootViewController = viewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        print("application executed")
        
        return true
    }
}
```

When I launch the simulator, the "application executed" is printed at console.

I am expecting to see a full screen red color once the app launched. However, I only can see an entire black screen.

May I know what else steps I have missed out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have scene life-cycle, so window should be created in `SceneDelegate`.

Here is `AppDelegate`:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
}
```

and now here is `SceneDelegate`

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let viewController = ViewController()
            viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = viewController
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```